# Grouping Elements in Dictionary by The Last Character of The Keys [iOS Swift 5]

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, swift5

I have a dictionary that I want to group by the last character of the keys. This is the dictionary:

```
var displayValues = ["volume_1": 1, "price_2": 6, "price_1": 2, "stock_1": 3, "volume_2": 5, "stock_2": 7]
```

This is the code that I used in order to group them

```
let groupValues = Dictionary(grouping: displayValues) { $0.key.last! }
print(groupValues)
```

This is the result of this code

```
["2": [(key: "price_2", value: 6), (key: "volume_2", value: 5), (key: "stock_2", value: 7)], "1": [(key: "volume_1", value: 1), (key: "price_1", value: 2), (key: "stock_1", value: 3)]]
```

The grouping is correct, however, how do I remove the words **key** and **value** from the dictionary so that it will display the following?

```
[
  "2": ["price_2": 6, "volume_2" : 5, "stock_2": 7], 
  "1": ["volume_1": 1, "price_1": 2, "stock_1": 3]
]
```

Comment: The words key and value aren't in the dictionary. That is just how the debug print formats the dictionary.

Comment: @Paulw11, the values are an array of `(key: String, value: Int)` tuples, and the OP wants the values to be `Dictionary<String,Int>`.

Comment: @vacawama your answer will result in a dictionary with key of type `String.Element` (Character) instead of  `String`.  Just use `String($0.key.suffix(1))` instead of `$0.key.last!`

Comment: Hello @LeoDabus thank you so much for the info. It did result to String.Element. I tried the code you suggested and got [String: [String:Any]] that is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are almost there !!

now You have key as you wanted and value as array of tuple

You can convert array of tuple into dictionary with new `reduce(into:)`

full code would be

```
    var displayValues = ["volume_1": 1, "price_2": 6, "price_1": 2, "stock_1": 3, "volume_2": 5, "stock_2": 7];
    let dict = Dictionary(grouping: displayValues) { $0.key.suffix(1)}
    let final = dict. mapValues { value  in
        return value.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.key] = $1.value }
    }
    print(final)
```

Output :

> ["2": ["price_2": 6, "volume_2": 5, "stock_2": 7], "1": ["price_1": 2, "stock_1": 3, "volume_1": 1]]

Comment: Using `compactMapValues` without ever returning `nil` is pointless. You can also get rid of the force unwrap of the last character of the key using `String($0.key.suffix(1))`. This will result in a dictionary with key of type `String` instead of `String.Element` (Character). To improve readability use the tuple naming `key` and `value` instead of `.0` and `.1`. Something like `let dict = Dictionary(grouping: displayValues) { String($0.key.suffix(1)) }.mapValues { $0.reduce(into: [:]) { $0[$1.key] = $1.value } }`

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya This will result in Substring keys. Check your resulting dictionary type  `let final: [String.SubSequence : [String : Int]]`

Comment: @LeoDabus Please suggest  What would be edit now. I mean what can be improved :))

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya my comment already did it. Just change `compactMapValues` to `mapValues` and initialize a new string with the suffix `String($0.key.suffix(1))`

Answer (score 2):

In this case, `Dictionary(grouping:by:)` creates a `Dictionary` of type `[Character : [(key: String, value: Int)]]`.  So the values are an array of `(key: String, value: Int)` tuples.

Use `.mapValues()` to convert the Array of `(key: String, value: Int)` tuples into a `Dictionary` by calling `Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues)` with the array:

```
var displayValues = ["volume_1": 1, "price_2": 6, "price_1": 2, "stock_1": 3, "volume_2": 5, "stock_2": 7]

let groupValues = Dictionary(grouping: displayValues) { String($0.key.suffix(1)) }
    .mapValues { Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: $0) }

print(groupValues)
```

**Result:**

> ```
> ["1": ["stock_1": 3, "price_1": 2, "volume_1": 1], "2": ["volume_2": 5, "stock_2": 7, "price_2": 6]]
> ```

---

**Note:**

To avoid a *force unwrap* (which will crash if you have an empty `String` as a key), I used `String($0.key.suffix(1))` instead of `$0.key.last!`.  This will make the final dictionary `[String : [String : Int]]` which can be conveniently indexed with a `String`.

Thanks to @LeoDabus for this suggestion.